# how to add new raw to the data frame during a loop and a certain condition is met?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-analysis

i want to add a new row when the iteration reach the raw which has 'total charges'.
FYI: as shown in code, column number 1 is where it has to be performed.

```
python
for row in df.itertuples():
    row[1] == 'Total Charges'
```

[this is how the data look like, i need to separate it with a row, right under total charges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Alw4r.png)

Comment: It depends on the structure of your data. Please an example of how you DataFrame looks like.

Comment: @dennis could you check the photo that i have added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope I understood you correctly (I used the data example you provided).
Iterate the rows and search for `Total Charges`. Then use `pandas.concat()`.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': ['data_row_1', 'data_row_2', 'Total Charges', 'data_row_3', 'data_row_4'], 'column2': range(1, 6)})

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['column1'] == 'Total Charges':
        df_before = df.iloc[:index+1]
        df_after = df.iloc[index+1:]
        new_row = pd.DataFrame({'column1': ['new_data_1'], 'column2': ['new_data_2']})
        new_df = pd.concat([df_before, new_row, df_after], ignore_index=True)
        break

print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
         column1     column2
0     data_row_1           1
1     data_row_2           2
2  Total Charges           3
3     new_data_1  new_data_2
4     data_row_3           4
5     data_row_4           5
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
import pandas as pd
s = list(range(3))
s.append('Total Charges')
s.extend(list(range(3)))
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': s, 'c2': range(7)})
ind = df[df['c1']=='Total Charges'].index
df.loc[ind[0]+.5]='',''
df = df.sort_index().reset_index()
del df['index']
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Note that [append](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) is deprecated since version 1.4.0 and `pd.concat` should be used instead.

Comment: @Jettus Joseph Updated the answer based on your question edit.